# SSIS Scope of the Global variable inside Eventhandler

Tags: ssis

As a part of package Error handling mechanism for one of the SSIS packages,

I have declared a variable V_ID(int32)  as global variable in SSIS and the initial value of this  variable is 0.
Now I assigned a value to this variable(say for example 1987) using a stored procedure output(using execute sql task in SSIS).

I had  to pass this vale to 2nd  stored procedure as input(It has been implemented using a execute sql task inside a Eventhandlers). But when I did the same I could see the value passing to the 2nd stored procedure is 
0 and not the value I got as a result of first stored procedure.

Do I have to change anything on variable expression to pertain the variable value?

All i need to know is If a variable has global scope and the value of that has been changed as a part of package
execution,how can i use this changed value inside the event handler .(I need to pass this changed value as an input of 2nd stored procedure when an event occur)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

On the Execute SQL Task, you will have to set the parameter to access the value. Have you done so already? When you say event handler, what kind of event handler it is?

Comment: thanks for the reply.I have already done all those stuffs.Now I have identified the problem the thing is it the output value is return as 0 from the first procedure.Now the real problem is the id which has been return as a part of first record is something like id=cast(scope_identify() as int),this is returning null.

Comment: What is the order of the Control flow tasks? Did you check the precedence and stuff?

Comment: The output value is return as 0 from the first procedure.Now the real problem is the id which has been return as a part of first procedure is something like id=cast(scope_identify() as int),    this is returning null.Now my question has become why cast(scope_identify() as int) returning null even though there is an identity column in the table.Just before this cast(scope_identify() as int) statement ,there is an insert statement (1 row insert) that is working fine and creating a unique identifier in the table ...then why cast(scope_identify() as int) this is not picking the last value??

Comment: You may want to post the sproc code here so that we can have a look and try to solve the issue.